# How to make the Name column in Ansible Tower longer?

Tags: ansible-tower

When viewing the Name column in 'Jobs' and 'Job Template' on Ansible I am not able to see the full name of some of my services.

Is there a way to customize the size of each field of remove ones I don't need to see?

Answer (score 0):

No. And I agree that the column is too narrow! Drives me crazy since my name are also long.